# How to create an object to the right side of the div (div:left)

Tags: javascript, html, css

We all know the pseudo-classes `:before` and `:after` but there is no `nav ul li a:left` or `:right`

Is it possible to achieve that? I don't mind using html5, css3, javascript for this.

Comment: Have you tried `float: left;` or `float: right;`?

Comment: No, I don't want that... I want something like `nav ul li a:left`

Comment: `text-align: left;`?

Comment: @Danielngx-development There is no such thing, you should align your pseudo element to left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `:before` and `:after` as `:left` and `:right`.

Both `:left` and `:right` don't exist as pseudo-classes and therefore you should use `:before` and `:after` to position to the left and right of whatever you want.

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
div:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -75px;
  background: red;
  content: 'To the left';
}
div:after {
  position: relative;
  right: -75px;
  background: green;
  content: 'right';
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
```

To answer the question

**Is it possible to achieve extra pseudo-classes?**

No.

**How do I achieve this effect?**

You'll have to use additional elements and alter your html to allow for it.

- [List of Pseudo Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Comment: The question is "Is it possible to achieve that?" and "How do I achieve that?"

Comment: @Danielngx-development then you will have to add more elements to be able to do what you want, sadly you can only have 3 areas per element which are the normal element, :before and :after

Comment: This is the valid answer and there is no way to make it. If you need positioning left and right some elements ( or top and bottom, or where you want), you need to add an element, and not pseudoelement.

Comment: There is no sadly, why you just dont make it by easy way - you can put there div in HTML, if you dont want it, do like @Stewartside said. Or just use jQuery.after() or put there new element by pure JS...